# Pythagorean triple problem

Tags: number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I am doing research on perfect cuboids, and I'm looking for values $a,b,c$ such that the following is integer, and I'm not sure how to continue this. Any suggestions are appreciated!
$PED$ is a very large constant=$899231100768000$

$$
\begin{align}
&\exp\left(\sigma_1+\sigma_2+\frac{\ln(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{2}-\ln(PED)
\right)\in\mathbb Z\\
&\sigma_1=\ln a+\ln b+\ln c\\
&\sigma_2=\frac{\ln(a^2+b^2)}{2}+\frac{\ln(b^2+c^2)}{2}+\frac{\ln(a^2+c^2)}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Another way to write this is:

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac {abc*\sqrt{a^2+b^2}*\sqrt{a^2+c^2}*\sqrt{b^2+c^2}*\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}{899231100768000}\in\mathbb Z\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It is well known that the diagonals of a parallelepiped cannot have all integer lengths, so I am afraid there are no solution no matter how big is the constant PED.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: references?

Comment: Jack you are seriously incorrect. (44,117,240) is just one that has all diagonal integers except the space diagonal. It is unknown whether there is one with an integer space diagonal. This formula would prove there is or there isn't however.

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2014-83-289/S0025-5718-2013-02791-3/S0025-5718-2013-02791-3.pdf

Comment: @daniel Yes you are correct. There are an infinite amount of perfect parallelepipeds, but perfect cuboids are an even more specific version. They have not been proven.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted a few days ago, Seth?

Comment: Are you still here, Seth?

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry finals week delayed my check -- thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=b=1$, $c=4$, then $$(a^2+b^2)(a^2+c^2)(b^2+c^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)=2\times17\times17\times18=102^2,$$ so $$abc\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{a^2+c^2}\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}=408$$ is an integer. Multiply each of $a,b,c$ by $899231100768000$, and you have an example.

Comment: Yes this is correct. Thank you -- as this was quite a bit a long time ago I will need to check where this will be used at. I will probably want to create parametric generators for a,b, and c to have all possibilities especially since this case does not have a and b unique

Answer (score -1):

assuming $a^2+b^2$, $a^2+c^2$, $b^2+c^2$, and $a^2+b^2+c^2$ are perfect squares, then it's impossible.

---

$\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(a^2+c^2)(b^2+c^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)}$

must be an integer, therefor

$(a^2+b^2)(a^2+c^2)(b^2+c^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$

must be a square, which allows us to assume that all terms are squares, and that makes the first 3 terms Pythagorean triples.

---

one method of generating Pythagorean triples is

for $A^2+B^2=C^2$

$A=2mn$
$B=m^2-n^2$
$C=m^2+n^2$

$n$ and $m$ must be integers to insure that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are integers

Note: every Pythagorean triple *must* include $A$, $B$, and $C$

---

if $a=A$
and $b=B$
then, because $a^2+c^2$ must equal $A^2+B^2$, $c$ must be $B$
and because $b^2+c^2$ must equal $B^2+A^2$, $c$ must be $A$
therefor $c=A$ and $c=B$. Which means

$A=B$
$2mn=m^2-n^2$

divide both sides by $mn$, simplify,

$2=\frac mn-\frac nm$

and since

$\frac nm = \frac 1{\frac mn}$

you have

$2=\frac mn-\frac 1{\frac mn}$

then if you introduce a new variable $x$

$x=\frac mn$

substitute $\frac mn$

$2=x-\frac 1x$

then multiply both sides by $x$,

$2x=x^2-1$
$0=x^2-2x-1$

and use the quadratic equation, you get.

$x=\frac {2\pm\sqrt{8}}2$

which you can simplify further into

$1+\sqrt{2}$ and $1-\sqrt{2}$

which means

$\frac mn=1+\sqrt{2}$
 or
$\frac mn=1-\sqrt{2}$

---

if we rearrange $A=2mn$, to get $\frac {A}{2n^2}=\frac mn$
then substitute $\frac mn$ and simplify, we see that

$A=2n^2(1+\sqrt{2})$
or
$A=2n^2(1-\sqrt{2})$

therefor, if $c$ is $A$ **and** $B$ (which it must be) then $c$ is irrational

you can do the same thing with $a$ and $b$, you will get the same contradiction.

---

ps. with the method of finding Pythagorean triples that I used, if you find one then you have found an infinite list of them by multiplying $a$, $b$, and $c$ by some integer $k$. If you do this for every integer pare $m$,$n$ you get almost all triples, the only ones missing are when $k=\frac {1}{2}$, but including that gets every triple that exists!
(including the ones that just flip $A$ and $B$ around) here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJYmyhnaaek) that can explain it better than I could.

ex: $m=2$, $n=1$
$3^2+4^2=5^2$, $k=1$
$6^2+8^2=10^2$, $k=2$
$9^2+12^2=15^2$, $k=3$
.
.
.

Comment: Your parameterization is not correct. What if some of the Pythagorean triples are not primitive?

Comment: @spydragon not correct  (44,117,240) is an example -- generate 44 and 117 from your list

Comment: Right (44,117), (44,240), (117,240) all work as "a" and "b" and they didn't fit the (3x)^2 expression you had in a comment above

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I now see the flaw you mentions a^2+b^2 could share a factor with one of the others, I will edit my answer to specify that they cannot share factors.

Comment: I am not sure which terms you are referring to in your most recent comment. If $a$ is even and $b,c$ are odd then $b^2+c^2$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2$ are both even, while if $a,b,c$ are all odd then $a^2+b^2$ and $a^2+c^2$ are both even.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet the terms I am referring to are $a^2+b^2$, $a^2+c^2$, $b^2+c^2$, and $a^2+b^2+c^2$. two of them could be a perfect square times a different number, and if a different term was also a perfect square times a different number and thous two different numbers are the same then the terms don't have to be perfect squares